# Matinee Keyframe issues UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am working in Unreal 4.19 and am trying to create a matinee. Every time I try to add keyframes, even though I have the items I want added to it selected, the system tells me that I don't have them selected. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Before you go too far down this path, I would recommend using Sequencer in place of Matinee - you'll find actor selections and interactions far more robust and easy to use than they were in Matinee. Matinee is a legacy tool that Epic has retained for backward compatibility, but is no longer maintained or updated.